Proportion of light rays blocked
I recently saw this problem somewhere:A ball is placed at the corner of a room (touching both walls and the floor, all mutually orthogonal).
Light rays are emitted from the corner, uniformly in all directions.
What proportion of the light rays are blocked by the ball? I think it has to do with solid angles but I am not able to dopve it

From the point at the corner the ball looks like a circular obstruction in one octant.
The task is to find its solid angle and divide it by $4\pi$, the full
solid angle of the emission into all 8 octants. (This is what "uniformly in all directions" means).
The ball has radius $r$, the center is at some cartesian coordinates $(cr,cr,cr)$ along the room diagonal,
with the factor $c$ determined by the touching-wall condition. The ball touches
the horizontal floor at $(dr,dr,0)$ and touches the vertical sides at $(dr,0,dr)$ and $(0,dr,dr)$, at the sides' diagonals.
The direction
to the points where the walls are touched relative to the ball's center (view point at the corner) is by the dot product
$$(cr,cr,cr)\cdot (dr,dr,0)= 2 dr cr = \cos\phi |(cr,cr,cr| |(dr,dr,0)|=\cos \phi cr\surd 3 dr \surd 2
$$,
$$
\cos\phi= \sqrt{2/3}.
$$
The solid angle of a sphere cap is $2\pi(1-\cos\phi)$.
So the result is $2\pi(1-\sqrt{2/3})/(4\pi)$.

I suppose you need a ratio of a ball's solid angle to the corner's solid angle, i.e., the denominator equals $4\pi/8=\pi/2.$ When emitting light 'from the corner', rays emitted towards walls or floor should not count, they are absorbed anyway, whether the ball is there or not.
